# Angular Protractor e2e mat-radio-group innerText iteration function error

Tags: angular, protractor, radio-group

```
clickOnQuestionsRadioButton(buttonName) {
    const matRadioButtonList = $$('mat-radio-group > mat-radio-button');
    const question_btn = matRadioButtonList.filter(elem => {
      return elem.getInnerText().then(text => {
        console.log(text);
        return text.toLowerCase().includes(buttonName.toLowerCase());
      });
    }).first().all(by.cssContainingText('innerText', buttonName));
    question_btn.click();
  }

clickOnQuestionsRadioButton('AEP');
```

[image]

**ERROR:**
TypeError: elem.getInnerText is not a function

Comment: I am not sure but can you try elem.element.getInnerText instead of elem.getInnerText?

Comment: @RounakSnehasis This didn't work, but thanks

Comment: Is getInnerText a function you have written yourself? It's not part of Protractor's api.

Comment: @Halfpenny As per the official protractor API list https://www.protractortest.org/#/api you can see there is no getInnerText APi. So I think this is the reason. You can do console.log(elem) and see the available list of APIs for the element instance.

Comment: @DublinDev I haven't written the funtion for innerText getting ahead of myself with var foo = element(by.id('foo'));
expect(foo.getText()).toEqual('Inner text');

Comment: @RounakSnehasis Thanks, I will try this now

Comment: I think xpath would work better in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `getInnerText()` use `getText()`.

`getInnerText()` function does not exist in Protractor API.